# Smarty inside javascript condition ... possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I am trying to have a javascript condition and mix it with smarty code...is this possible?

For example:

```
<script>

if (myjsVar == '2') {
    {some smarty here}
}

</script>
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  myjsVar = '2';
  if (myjsVar == '2') {
    {include file='inc.html'}
}
</script>
{/literal}
```

At this moment this code is not including anything ...syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [literal](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal.tpl) that allows a block of data to be taken literally.Eg Javascript or CSS

> {literal} tags allow a block of data to be taken literally. This is
>   typically used around Javascript or stylesheet blocks where {curly
>   braces} would interfere with the template delimiter syntax. Anything
>   within {literal}{/literal} tags is not interpreted, but displayed
>   as-is. If you need template tags embedded in a {literal} block,
>   consider using {ldelim}{rdelim} to escape the individual delimiters
>   instead.

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
if (myjsVar == '2') {
    {include file='inc.html'}
}
</script>
{/literal}
```

You can also use [{ldelim} and {rdelim}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl) that is used for escaping smartys template delimeters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (myjsVar == '2') {ldelim}
    {include file='inc.html'}
{rdelim}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Smarty 3 templates, the { and } braces will be ignored so long as they are surrounded by whitespace.

You can use following without literal escapement.

```
<script>
if (myjsVar == '2') {
    {some smarty here}
}
</script>
```

Following code requires literal escapement.

```
{literal}
    function bazzy() {alert('foobar!');}
{/literal}
```

Optionally you can also change Smarty delimiters like so:

```
<?php

$smarty->left_delimiter = '{{';
$smarty->right_delimiter = '}}';
```

Answer (score 2):

Smarty version 2 is confused by the curly braces used by Javascript code; it tries to interpret them as open tags. To avoid this issue, the content of the `<script>` element is usually enclosed in a [`{literal}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl) Smarty block.

The drawback is that you have to close the `{literal}` block and open it again if you need to use Smarty functions to generate a fragment of the Javascript block.

In Smarty 2, it works like this:

```
{assign var="text" value="Hello world!"}
<script>
{literal}
if (myjsVar == '2') {
    alert('{/literal}
    {* Smarty code here *}
    {$text|escape:'javascript'}
    {*
     * End of the Smarty code; start another 'literal' block
     * for the rest of the Javascript code
     *}
{literal}');
}
{/literal}
</script>
```

The generated text looks like this:

```
<script>
if (myjsVar == '2') {
    alert('Hello world!');
}
</script>
```

Smarty 3 doesn't need enclosing the script in a `{literal}` block as long as the curly braces (`{` and `}`) are surrounded by whitespace characters.

**Update:**

Alternatively, if the block of Javascript contains just a few braces and a lot of Smarty code you can forget about the `{literal}` blocks and use [`{ldelim}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl) and [`{rdelim}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl) for `{` and `}`.

Like this:

```
{assign var="text" value="Hello world!"}
<script>
if (myjsVar == '2') {ldelim}
    alert('{$text|escape:'javascript'}');
    {include file="inc.html"}
{rdelim}
</script>
```

It works the same in both Smarty versions 2 and 3.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do: {literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  myjsVar = '2';
  if (myjsVar == '2') {
    {include file='inc.html'}
}
</script>
{/literal}

Comment: Smarty doesn't parse the content of `{literal}` blocks. You have to close the `{literal}` block before `{include}` and open a new one after it. Like this: `{literal} <script type="text/javascript"> myjsVar = '2'; if (myjsVar == '2') { {/literal}{include file='inc.html'}{literal} } </script> {/literal}`

Comment: It's ignoring the condition. if you change myjsVar to anything else you get the same result for some reason

Comment: Smarty code runs on the server and generates the HTML and Javascript code. The generated Javascript code runs on the visitor's browser. Don't confuse them.

Comment: Issue I'm having is that I have the variables on JS and what to create a JS condition to include different files depending on the variable value

Comment: You cannot control the execution of the Smarty template from Javascript because they run on different computers and when Javascript takes control, the Smarty template (and the PHP code that drives is) are completed. Can you go back in time to change what file is included? I guess not. But you can generate a big list of `if/else` blocks and include all the files you need in a single `<script>` block. Like this: <script>if (myjsVar == '1'){ {include file="inc1.html"} } else if (myjsVar == '2') { {include file="inc2.html"} }` a.s.o. You'll get a big script that contains all the code.

Answer (score 0):

try below :

```
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image_src = '{/literal}{$image}{literal}';
        alert(image_src);
    </script>
{/literal}
```

or

```
{literal}
<script language="javascript">

function ab()
{

////What you need

}
</script>
{/literal}

<a href="javascript:ab();">Something you need</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign smarty variable to javascript

```
{literal}
<script>

if (myjsVar == '2') {
    {/literal}{include file='inc.html'}{literal}
}

</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: If you try:   myjsVar = '1';
if (myjsVar == '2') { .... I'm still getting the include